# Find all urls for each array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

Given the following array structure:

`{ url: "www.site.com", ids: ["F20", "C10", "C05"] }, { url: "www.site.com/something", ids: ["F20", "C06", "C05"] }, { url: "www.site.com/somethingelse", ids: ["F21", "C12", "C05"] }`

I’m trying to loop over the array and find all urls for each id. So the end result would group the urls where an id value has the same url:

F20 for instance would have [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) and [www.site.com/something](http://www.site.com/something).

The data structure would end up being an array of objects where each id would have an array of urls in which the id exists.

I have started with a basic for loop, but stuck on the best way to loop over and check the url for each value of the array it’s associated with and then group by id.

`for(id of ids){ console.log(id) }`

The end result would be a list of ids with all associated urls where that id appears.

Comment: You could groupd the URLs in a structure: `{ id1: [url1, url2, ...], ... }`

Comment: @jabaa - I have a node script that programmatically generates the array of objects for this, and there are almost 200. I need a way to loop over the existing structure and programmatically build the arrays based on my criteria.

Comment: Have you tried a quick search for _"group by property"_? You should find a dozen similar questions with solutions. What have you tried? What are you struggling with? Iterate over the array and fill the structure described in my first comment.

Comment: another approach would be to have an empty array outside and loop your array and check if subelement.ids.includes('F20'). if that returns true push element.url to the empty array

Comment: you can also use filter and map. inside the filter check if the ids array includes F20. then it will return the filtered elements. then map it to return only the urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over input array and then loop over ids for each input element and keep adding urls for corresponding ids. For e.g.

```
const input = [{ url: "www.site.com", ids: ["F20", "C10", "C05"] }, { url: "www.site.com/something", ids: ["F20", "C06", "C05"] }, { url: "www.site.com/somethingelse", ids: ["F21", "C12", "C05"] }]
const output = {}
input.forEach(obj=>{
    const ids = obj.ids
    if(ids && ids.length>0){
        ids.forEach(id=>{
            if(!output[id]){
                output[id] = []
            }
            output[id].push(obj.url)
        })
    }
})

for(let id of Object.keys(output)){
    console.log(`${id}:${JSON.stringify(output[id])}`)
}
```

Comment: That’s what I had in mind, but was having trouble with the implementation. Perfect, thank you!